# Setting scaling to 1, but keeping object size in meters

Tags: scale, hdri

I open a new file in Blender, so I get the Cube. The edge lengths of the Cube are 2 meters. Now I change the scale factor from 1 to 2, so the edges grow to 4 meters.

**Is there a way to set the scale factor to 1 again, while the edges maintain length 4 meters?**

I need this feature to solve a problem with HDRI environment textures. My object is a car, and it is too small for the roads in the HDRI panorama. The proportions in meters of the car are correct, but it has a scale factor of 0.3. I suspect the scale factor has to be 1 for the meter size of the object to match correctly with the HDRI.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + A then click Scale, this will reset your scale

Answer (score 2):

Environment image (HDR or not) just mapped on infinite sphere.
The scale of you object (cube or car) not doesn't affect environment of depend on it.
Only for still camera you can adjust your model to environment using camera orientation and focal length.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OZre.jpg

Nonetheless to apply scale: select objects to be applied, go 3d Viewport menu > Object > Apply > Scale (or All Transforms)
[image: Apply Scale]